# TVGuide database recurring TV Show

Tags: duplication

I am trying to design TVGuide database
[image]

as you can see one TV program can have many shows, as well as one show can play on multiple tv programes

this is all going fine

The problem I am trying to solve is what to do when show is on multiple dates, for example a movie is on BBC 1 at 04/04/2012 and then they play it again at 08/08/2012 right now I would have duplicate movies with different dates, is it possible to reduce this somehow, so I would have one movie with many dates or (a movie can also be played only once) something like that

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards
BTW: I am using Toad data modeler 6.5 to design this db in and here is its design: https://www.mediafire.com/file/lek90uvy8pz9wr8/TVGuide.txp/file

Comment: As you have noticed, a presentation of a TV show is its own entity, whose attributes are start and end times, possibly among others.

Comment: ok but if then there will be like 5 entities with the same name, description and other stuff, while the onlything that would change is start and end time, so this duplication is something that concerns me

Comment: No duplication: a "TV Show" entity is a parent of a "TV Show Presentation" entity.

Comment: oh I see, so if I understand this corecly the design I curently have, if I put like 3 Home Alones as TVShow (one starts today, second one tomorow, third one, yesterday) then it will still not waste any space even if there are 3 identitical names but have different start and end dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In similar vein to what mustaccio is getting at in the comments, I'd make another table called something along the lines of `TV_Schedule`. It could have the columns `(TV_Schedule_ID, TV_Show_TV_Station_ID, Airtime_Start, Airtime_End)` and would be a child table that's foreign key related to `TV_Show_TV_Station` by the column `TV_Show_TV_Station_ID`. This would be a one-to-many relationship.

This way you wouldn't manage the presentations in the `TV_Show` table, causing unneeded duplicate data.